# How to get YUI editor to pass its contents

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, yui

Im trying to use the YUI Rich Text editor on an asp mvc site Im using this javascript code

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('Body', {
    height: '300px',
    width: '522px',
    dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
    animate: true //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows
});
myEditor.render();
```

``

On this textarea

```
<div class="yui-skin-sam">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { cols = "50", rows = 10 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
        </div>
```

The editor loads, but its contents is not being passed when I submit the form I keep getting a validation message saying that the feild is required as I should if there was nothing in it.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work how I want ?

Comment: Also, I have viewed the source and the name and id of the textarea IS indeed Body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution if anyone else ends up with this problem.

You can TRY setting handleSubmit:true like this

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('Body', {
height: '300px',
width: '522px',
dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
animate: true, //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows
handleSubmit: true
```

});
myEditor.render();

The editor will attempt to attach itself and automaticly call my myEditor.saveHTML() which stuffs the content back into the textarea. If that fails as it did for me, manually do it by setting up an event like below.

```
   YAHOO.util.Event.on('somebutton', 'click', function() {

myEditor.saveHTML();
alert("test");
});
```

where somebutton is the name of your submit button for the form.

When you get this working, the second problem your going to have is asp.net will error out when it finds html tags in your model. It is a different problem so I wont describe the solution here.